# Can you ask for start date to be pushed back after signing the contract of employment?

Tags: new-job, contracts, start-date

So I signed the contract for a new job that states a specific start date. However, due to some reasons, I have to push it back a week.

Is it possible/frowned upon now that my signed contract already has a start date set?

EDIT:
All sorted - they are happy to push it back a week. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Are those reasons something that you can't change? In other words, pushing back the date is the only option here?

Comment: Let's just say it would be immensely helpful if it could be pushed back.

Comment: That means that those reasons could be put aside without pushing the start date, even if that is an inconvenience to you. Correct?

Comment: Another question, how long is it until you start this new job?

Comment: That's correct. I start mid next month.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I included an answer for you to consider. Seems that you have one month before you actually start so I am sure this situation will be sorted out :) Welcome to The Workplace BTW.

Comment: It’s a bit unprofessional but most people understand that “life happens.” If you expect them to be understanding, though, you’ll have to be a lot more specific about your reasons than you’ve been here.

Comment: All sorted - they are happy to push it back a week.

Comment: Just as a general tip: the answer to "can you ask" is always yes. You can ask anything, reasonable or not. It helps to refine the question down to what you're actually interested in: will it reflect badly on you for asking, can you guarantee that you get what you ask, can you legally enforce getting what you're asking for, is it impossible to get what you're asking for, ... If we know your end goal, we can answer more precisely.

Answer (score 4):

> However, due to some reasons, I have to push it back a week.

It'll depend on the reason.  Don't just say, "due to reasons" - actually add details about the reason.  Explain the circumstances and why this was not known when you negotiated your start date.  They might say yes!

Especially considering that you could have simply asked for the date to be one week later there is a good chance this won't be a big deal.  **Contact them now - the longer you wait the more likely they will say no.**

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible/frowned upon now that my signed contract already has a start date set?

It's always possible to ask.

If they will like it or not will depend on how this company takes it, so we can't guess that. However, unforeseen situations can happen in any context, so it is understandable that a situation could have come up that changes things.

My suggestion is that you **talk to them ASAP, explain the circumstances that happened, why it is not possible (or really hard) to postpone them, and politely ask if the start date could be postponed or if there is some agreement you could reach.**